# how to remove specific tr border in table -bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i need to remove specific tr border in my table.
in bootstrap its come automaticly when i put "tr" element.
this is my table:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-sm table-dark">
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>bbb</td>
                    <td>AAA</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>AAA</td>
                    <td>bbb</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>18:00</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>19/10/2018</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

i want the middle border of "tr" element not show. i cant success do taht

[image]

Comment: Have you tried css to do this

Comment: yes. It did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect the regarding css items via F12 or just right click on item and choose "inspect element". Menue naming depends on your browser.